# WebBrowser control using project resources

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, embedded-resource

I have a WinForm app with a WebBrowser control on it. I create HTML programmatically. How do I use images from the **project's resources** inside the HTML?
Visual Basic 2010 Express.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body style='background-image:url(???);background-color:#DDEEFF'>Some text.</body></html>"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. Basically, the `WebBrowser` control doesn't work well when you set `DocumentText` directly.

The solution I came up with is to implement a tiny HTTP server in your app and point the `WebBrowser` control to that url.

You then have complete control over **all** the content.

I wrote an article about it here: [`WebBrowserEx: WinForms WebBrowser + HTTP Server`](http://simplygenius.net/Article/WebBrowserEx)

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler way, but I guess not. Could you illustrate how to use an embedded resource with your browser class? Thanks.

Comment: I hoped there was a simpler way too! This solution is the best way I found that worked properly. If you use the code from my article, you can modify the `ListenerCallback` method to respond to certain urls by returning the embedded resources.